# Which web server should I use ? Apache vs Lighthttpd vs nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, lighttpd

Could you help me to choose a webserver. I would like to change my Apache installation on a cloud server.
I'm using PHP, Node.js and maybe one day Python.

Which one of Apache, Ligthttpd and nginx is the simplest to configure for my use ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your use, exactly? It would be difficult to provide you with an accurate answer without knowing more about your intentions.

Comment: It's for personal sites. Actually I have two Drupal sites, one node.js site, and in the future a PHP Symfony site. Traffic handling is not a big deal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intend to run Node.js alongside PHP on the same platform, I would suggest looking into using nginx as a reverse proxy.

There are several advantages to this setup..

- Although nginx is fully capable of handling php requests via fastcgi, but Apache + mod_php is simpler to configure in my personal opinion.
- EngineX is superb at serving static files, it requires far less memory than Apache thus allowing you to rely on Apache only for dynamic PHP requests.
- Provided you are running some flavor of linux, you can install both Apache and nginx through a package manager and avoid dealing with source unless you want to.
- Node.js can run as an upstream server through nginx so you would be able to run all 3 servers at the same time.

I have never tried implementing Python via nginx so I have no experience with it, but given how efficient nginx as a reverse proxy, you can throw a Python server on a different port and simply add another upstream server to your nginx configuration with barely any effort.